# Is it possible to abandon desire by means of desire

Tags: pali-canon, texts, teaching

Regarding previous Question [Desire without attachment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10983/desire-without-attachment/10993#10993).
If desire without the attachment still lead to suffering then how abandon desire without desire?
As shown by [Unnabha the Brahman](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn51/sn51.015.than.html) 
it's an endless path, and not one with an end, for it's impossible that one could abandon desire by means of desire."

Comment: The sutta you referenced ends with Unnabha conceding to Ven. Ananda that it is, in fact, a path with an end.

Comment: This question is also a duplicate of [Stopping Tanha or craving](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8776/254)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda simple. First we abandon desires. Only then we abandon the desire to give up desires. As per the traditional metaphor, you should not leave "the raft" until you are safely "on the other shore".

Sure, the desire to abandon desires also causes suffering. But that's the price we pay. It is like with the surgeon inflicting more pain short-term to end the pain long-term.

My point is, it is only a paradox in theory, once we get to real kitchen-level practice, to action -- there is no paradox.